# Display more info on fullCalendar Jquery dependent on the dayname

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Am using Jquery fullCalendar,

Am trying to do a daily booking system , so i want users to see the price for the days  , display ( Price ) on every cell on the calendar
the prices is changes per daysName , Not date , price is fixed for every sunday .. 
for example 
every Sunday : 700$
every Monday : 600$
every Tuesday: 700$

Note that, I want to keep the events,which will be the users booking events.. can i do it ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Tfv.png)

Comment: Did you check the documentation or try any code yet? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayRender lets you modify the HTML element which represents a specific day and add your extra content to it. The callback also gives you access to the date which the cell represents, so of course you can easily extract the day name from that in order to vary the price.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you , yes dayRender solve the issue for me